# Zend Framework plugins/modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, symfony1

The symfony framework has a lot of plugins for adding functionalities like a user system (login, registration, authentication, etc..), so users won't have to invent the wheel from scratch, as a user system is a basic need for most applications (for example).

I have tried finding an equivalent in Zend Framework, and though there is the concept of plugins in Zend Framework, I couldn't find any plugins out there, which one can download and add to his project.

Is it possible Zend Framework does not have this wonderful community feature such as the vast amount of plugins available in symfony ?

Comment: There are many articles about how to create a basic user authentication system in Zend Framework. Just use Google. Once you do it you can just copy paste it into every new ZP application you create and just make needed changes. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Plugin isn't the same as what  you are thinking. The terminilogy betwen Symfony and ZF are completely different.

A Plugin does not mean "Plug me in" I will work on your website. It is basically the name given to something which the developer uses in his applications which are called every page load. Rather then creating a base controller, or some other kind of helper, a plugin is used to kind of create a new abstraction from your controllers. When you create a plugin, your reason should be that the code used therein needs to be used on each page load.

On my site here are examples of some plugins

- My ACL
- My template manager. (I built a unique template engine)

Some people might even use it for caching.. however, to answer your question, you would not use plugins in the way you want.

In answer to your comment below:
No, a module is just a way of creating  different layer of features on your site, which is seperate from the default module.

ie.. 
Example Modules
- a Blog
- a Fully fledged online store
- an administration suite

These naturally want to be seperate from your default module..

If I were you, I would implement a plugin. However you need to create your plugin yourself. Readily available ones aren't really.. provided anywhere. Fortunately however, the documentation shows you exactly how to implement something.

I would definately recommend using ZF, it is the best thing I have ever experienced in my coding career. I love it.

Comment: Ok, so:

1) What would I use? Modules (as @Gordon said above)?

2) Is there a repository of such modules (or whatever they are called) ?


I'm especially interested in a users/ACL module.

Comment: Please see my revised ansswer above.

Comment: I must say that according to what I read in these answers, yours specifically, I can't agree with what you say about ZF being better then symfony.

There is no reason at all, for someone to reinvent the wheel where so many people out there have already invented it.
A user ACL module/plugin/whatever you want to call it, is something that will mostly have the same 'guts' in most of the applications, with some modifications here and there.

It is sad that there is no such repository of ready components, as symfony has.

Comment: I didn't actually say ZF is better than Symfony in my post. I try and stay clear of subjective opinions in answers, however I do believe that it is better. (I just didn't say so above - At least I think I didn't)

Answer (score 5):

There is [ZFSnippets](http://zfsnippets.com/). A full fledged user administration would be a *module* in ZF terms. I am not aware of a ready-to-use modules download page.

Comment: There are the base modules for authentication and ACL which should be sufficient for most needs.

Comment: @Htbaa Yes, but `Zend_Auth` and `Zend_Acl` are neither *modules*, nor *plugins*. I think the OP wants to download a set of models, views and controllers that he just needs to add to his app and have a working user admin module.